# How to update an user without changing his credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I use [sorcery gem](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) to manage authentification. You can see the code below.

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery! 

  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :clients
  has_many :orders

  validates_presence_of :email, :username, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_confirmation_of :password, :message => "confirmation doesn't match password " 
  validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 6
end
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_login, :except => [:not_authenticated, :new, :create]
    skip_authorize_resource :only => [:new, :create]

    layout "users"

  def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        redirect_to clients_url, :notice => "Bienvenu dans la communauté Bakden!!!"
      else
        render :new
      end
    end


 #show user profile
  def show
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

            respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @user }
        end
      end

# edit user profile
  def edit
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])  
  end

# update user profile

  def update
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
        format.json  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for (@user),:html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input :adress %>
    <%= f.input :city %>
    <%= f.input :country ,:as => :country %>
    <%= f.input :telephone, :as => :string %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture %>     

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %> | <%= link_to "cancel", profile_path%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How can I edit the users informations like adress, telephone... without affecting the password, email and username which are the credentials.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [best-in-place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem to edit specific fields. Here is a video tut by Ryan Bates [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing).

TO see a test example check [this](http://bipapp.heroku.com/).

I find this to be the fastest and easiest way to edit specific fields without hampering user experience, and will definitely work if you just want to update specific fields like telephone and address. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding so diligently.Sure best in place can make it.But I want to use a separate form to have the whole perpective of the problem

Answer (score 2):

Sample code, from Devise, this goes in your user model:

```
  # Update record attributes when :current_password matches, otherwise returns
  # error on :current_password. It also automatically rejects :password and
  # :password_confirmation if they are blank.
  def update_with_password(params, *options)
    current_password = params.delete(:current_password)

    if params[:password].blank?
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
    end

    result = if valid_password?(current_password)
      update_attributes(params, *options)
    else
      self.attributes = params
      self.valid?
      self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
      false
    end

    clean_up_passwords
    result
  end

  # Set password and password confirmation to nil
  def clean_up_passwords
    self.password = self.password_confirmation = nil
  end
```

Comment: I can see the direction the direction but I still doesn't work.When I go to the rails console the adress and telephone attributes are nil

Comment: I don't see what you mean .. ? Is address and telephone in the params hash ? Is :current_password given and valid in the params hash?

Comment: No they don't. So params[:user] is not enough?

Comment: Add to your form the "current_password" password input, so the user proves his identity when changing data, or remove the `if valid_password?(current_password)` check from code.